# Bypass battery of UPS

Tags: batteries, ups

I have DC-UPS
http://www.mercury-pc.com/product-detail.php?link=p-ups&subtitle=UPS&productid=1255

I want to make this ups bypass battery(by using a switch),
the switch connect and disconnect battery from ups,
when main power off the ups will use the battery if the switch on, and not use battery when the switch off

[image]

i try to do that and its work.
but i wonder , disconnecting battery by this way a good idea? is it possible to damage the UPS?

Comment: Depends how your UPS is made internally. It may do anything from work as intended to break. Serious UPS manufacturers allows hot swapping the batteries for their professional UPSes. Check your manual.

Comment: This probably will not work as intended. First the battery is trickle charged, if you disconnect it, it won't be charged, but even more than that you may not be able to switch them out while the UPS is running (as commented above).

Comment: i will disconnect battery during night only, and connect it rest of day,
sure i will not connect and disconnect battery when ups is runnig

Comment: Another XY problem -- what are you really trying to solve?

Comment: So what is your goal then? Why do you want to disconnect the battery?

Comment: ok :), in my region main power turn off many time especially at night, so at night i dont want to drain battery when its not needed
i cannot just turn off  the ups(it's complicated story)

Comment: Is it the case that you generally want the UPS to be supplying power at night but if the power goes out thats fine and you dont want UPS protection then? Or is it something else?

Comment: Matt 1, yes that what i want

Comment: when i disconnect battery then run ups, the transformer give notable noise, so that make me wonder